# Extract Table Outputs like Summary and ANOVA from a "by" Object

Tags: r

I have a regression model created with `by`. I know I can use `sapply` to extract specific parts of the model for each factor, but what if I wanted something like the whole `summary`, `anova`, etc.?

```
 model <- with(data, by(data, factor, function(data) lm(y ~ x, data=data)))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Next time, please post a [**minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). It makes it much easier to test code when trying to help you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sapply` will coerce the results of `summary.lm` and `anova.lm` to a matrix. I think you may want to use `lapply`, which applies a function (here `summary`) on each element in the list produced by `by`, and returns a list.

```
models <- by(warpbreaks, warpbreaks$tension, function(x){
  lm(breaks ~ wool, data = x)
  })

lapply(models, summary)
```